saving and reading a duckdb database in R
I'm learning more about duckdb and exploring the various ways to "save" a database. I understand I should be able to save a duckdb database however when I try to save it, I get an error.
Error: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for signature ‘conn = "duckdb_connection", name = "character", value = "tbl_duckdb_connection"’

Ultimately, I am experimenting with the best ways to save and load data to duckdb by trying to save a database itself (not just the csv or parquet files).
If you have any thoughts on the benefits or challenges of this approach vs. csv /parquet please let me know.
After saving the database, I'd also like to load it as well (which I give the code for but sure if it works because I can't save it)
Lastly, I created the duckdb connection via a temp file which I understand will create a persistence file and allow me to work out of memory vs. the regular duckdb() which limits me to in memory (https://josiahparry.com/posts/2024-05-24-duckdb-and-r)
Any suggestions?
library(tidyverse)
library(duckdb)

# this works -- but I have limited understanding of the implications between duckdb() only vs. the below solution

drv <- duckdb(tempfile(fileext = ".duckdb"))

# this works
con <- dbConnect(drv)

# this works
duckdb_register(con,"diamonds",diamonds,overwrite = TRUE)

# this works
diamonds_db <- dplyr::tbl(con, sql("select * from diamonds"))

# this doesn't work -- I'm trying to save this as duckdb database object (as oppose to a csv file or parquet file) -- I am assuming this is better saving format (eg. lighter?)

duckdb::dbWriteTable(
  con
  ,"data/diamonds.duckdb"
  ,diamonds_db
  ,append = TRUE)
)

Ideally if I can figure out how to save it, I can also read from it with what I assume will work as below
library(tidyverse)
library(duckdb)

con <- dbConnect(
  duckdb::duckdb(),
  dbdir = "data/diamonds.duckdb"
)

# I don't know if this works
df <- dbReadTable(con, "diamonds")


Always include full code and complete error messages.

A duckdb database is a directory, not a file.  If  you are trying to write a copy of a data frame to the database use dbWriteTable instead of duckdb_register.

Hi -- so I understand dbWriteTable will write an R dataframe to my connection. So then I can use dplyr::tbl() to access it, etc. How do I save my registered tables to a database? Do I need to write it back as a csv? I guess I'm trying to understand how to save an actual database with registered objects? or do I just save things with csv files?

Use a permanent directory instead of a temporary one.

hi! thanks -- so in duckdb() I change from temp to a permanent directory. then I can use dbWriteTable() to write a table to the connection. From there do I need to anything else? The next time i spin up duckdb with reference to the table will it load those tables I loaded from the previous session?

@G.Grothendieck - a duckdb database is a single file that encapsulates all content, not a directory.

thanks -- I think i got it to work. I had to wrap the database reference in ' to make it work. Does a database compress the data? it is more efficient to store that way vs. just a csv file?

See https://duckdb.org/docs/internals/storage.html#disk-usage

thank so this answers my question. should I take down the question or edit and answer it?

thanks to @G. Grothendieck, the problem was my approach is two fold:

I was using a temporary file for the database, so even if I was successful in saving a table to it, the database itself wouldn't save
I was using dudckdb::duckdb_register() which creates a temporary table (that you can use and collect) but won't actually save it to database.

Below is the corrected code
library(tidyverse)
library(duckdb)

drv <- duckdb(dbdir ="database.duckdb")


con <- dbConnect(drv)


duckdb::dbWriteTable(
  con
  ,"diamonds.dbi"
  ,diamonds
  ,append = TRUE)
)

This will successfully save your table your database.
If you quite and start a new session, simply reconnect to your database and then use dplyr::tbl() to access it (no need to read csv files).

drv <- duckdb(dbdir ="database.duckdb")


con <- dbConnect(drv)

## this loads your table from your persistance database

tbl(con,sql("select * from 'diamonds.dbi'"))

Ensure you wrap reference to your table with ' or it won't work.

A few notes. First, make sure to dbDisconnect() when using a writeable connection to the database. Second, things work more smoothly using read_only = TRUE if it's not necessary to write when using the database later on. Third, another option is to write to a parquet file, as the performance loss is often negligible and you have a file that is a little easier to work with in other contexts.
